# Why do I need to pay to have my CV searchable?

Tags: support, jobs

I have a quick question

Did I just spent an hour filling my CV just to be told I have to pay $19 for it to be searchable?

...

Now that's annoying. I mean, I realize that stack overflow needs funding and all, but please let people know before they fill they CVs.

Answer (score 8):

I see this on the "Edit your CV" page:

[image]

Comment: No, I think it isn't (I missed it at least) ...

Comment: @droope I just tested it with a new account and it definitely is always visible. (I might have overlooked it too, but I don't think the team can be blamed here - it *is* pretty clear)

Comment: Yeah, i've looked back and it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 3):

I now understand ( I have read [the FAQ](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq#pricing) ).

The fee is in order to prove that you are relly interested in getting a job.

Sorry (still very annoying) :P